# I'm trying to reduce this code

Tags: php

My php knowledge is not of the strongest part. I'm trying to reduce this code, but really do not know how. maybe have any advice for how to do it?

```
if (isset($this->data['upload_main_bg_pattern_image']) && $this->data['upload_main_bg_pattern_image'] != "" && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $this->data['upload_main_bg_pattern_image'])) {
    $this->data['image_pattern_preview'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($this->data['upload_main_bg_pattern_image'], 100, 100);
} else {
    $this->data['image_pattern_preview'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.jpg', 100, 100);
}

if (isset($this->data['upload_main_full_bg_image']) && $this->data['upload_main_full_bg_image'] != "" && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $this->data['upload_main_full_bg_image'])) {
    $this->data['image_main_full_bg_preview'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($this->data['upload_main_full_bg_image'], 100, 100);
} else {
    $this->data['image_main_full_bg_preview'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.jpg', 100, 100);
}

if (isset($this->data['upload_header_bg_pattern_image']) && $this->data['upload_header_bg_pattern_image'] != "" && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $this->data['upload_header_bg_pattern_image'])) {
    $this->data['image_header_pattern_preview'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($this->data['upload_header_bg_pattern_image'], 100, 100);
} else {
    $this->data['image_header_pattern_preview'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.jpg', 100, 100);
}

if (isset($this->data['upload_header_full_bg_image']) && $this->data['upload_header_full_bg_image'] != "" && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $this->data['upload_header_full_bg_image'])) {
    $this->data['image_header_full_bg_preview'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($this->data['upload_header_full_bg_image'], 100, 100);
} else {
    $this->data['image_header_full_bg_preview'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.jpg', 100, 100);
}
```

Comment: Would I be correct in observing that the only difference between the four `if/else` statements is the name of the key in `data` that's being called?

Comment: @ASGM: Looks that way.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing

```
isset($this->data['upload_main_bg_pattern_image']) && $this->data['upload_main_bg_pattern_image'] != ""
```

You should do`!empty($this->data['upload_main_bg_pattern_image'])`

And so on for each of your statement

Answer (score 2):

this should be a function

```
   if (isset($this->data['upload_header_full_bg_image']) && $this->data['upload_header_full_bg_image'] != "" && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $this->data['upload_header_full_bg_image'])) {
        $this->data['image_header_full_bg_preview'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($this->data['upload_header_full_bg_image'], 100, 100);
    } else {
        $this->data['image_header_full_bg_preview'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.jpg', 100, 100);
    }
```

repeat it 4 times passing image names and all the stuff you need

Comment: another big issue with your code is the multiple && clauses inside the if() statement. As per standard, statements evaluation order is undefined so the isset() statement *could* be evaluated after the others resulting in an unpredictable behavior of the whole if().

Answer (score 2):

You could add

```
$data = $this->data;
```

in front of it and then operate on `$data` with the following code instead of `$this->data`.

The next step then is to extract the strings into variables.  That works per each part:

```
$upload_main_bg = 'upload_main_bg_pattern_image';
$image_pattern  = 'image_pattern_preview';
$image_default  = 'no_image.jpg';

if (isset($data[$upload_main_bg]) && $data[$upload_main_bg] != "" && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $data[$upload_main_bg])) {
    $data[$image_pattern] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($data[$upload_main_bg], 100, 100);
} else {
    $data[$image_pattern] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($image_default, 100, 100);
}
```

After that you also extract the exists and resize function calls:

```
$exists = function($path) {
    return file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $path);
};

$resize = function($image) {
    return $this->model_tool_image->resize($image, 100, 100);
};

...

if (isset($data[$upload_main_bg]) && $data[$upload_main_bg] != "" && $exists($data[$upload_main_bg])) {
    $data[$image_pattern] = $resize($data[$upload_main_bg]);
} else {
    $data[$image_pattern] = $resize($image_default);
}
```

And then you extract this whole block:

```
$image = function(&$subject, $default = NULL) use ($exists, $image_default) {
    if ($default === NULL) {
        $default = $image_default;
    }
    if (strlen($subject) && $exists($subject)) {
        return $subject;
    }
    return $default;
};
```

Pass-by-reference is used so that you can pass undefined variables without any warning.

You then make use of it:

```
$data[$image_pattern] = $resize($image($data[$upload_main_bg]));
```

That line than replaces `if` block you have so far.

The next step then is to put the information of the different images into an array and iterate over it:

```
$images = [
    ['upload_main_bg_pattern_image',   'image_pattern_preview'       ],
    ['upload_main_full_bg_image',      'image_main_full_bg_preview'  ],
    ['upload_header_bg_pattern_image', 'image_header_pattern_preview'],
    ['upload_header_full_bg_image',    'image_header_full_bg_preview'],
];

foreach($images as $imageData)
{
    list($name, $result) = $imageData;
    $data[$result] = $resize($image($data[$name]));
}
```

Which then as well shows that the names only differ by their prefix and postfix, so you can encode this even further. But this does not work because the first is different. So you should consider easing the data-structure you use here first to get a benefit within the code. Same for the third element:

```
$images = [
    ['upload_main_bg_pattern_image',   'image_main_bg_pattern_preview'  ],
    ['upload_main_full_bg_image',      'image_main_full_bg_preview'     ],
    ['upload_header_bg_pattern_image', 'image_header_bg_pattern_preview'],
    ['upload_header_full_bg_image',    'image_header_full_bg_preview'   ],
];
```

This would then allow to have two masks and just the image names:

```
$patternInput  = 'upload_%s_image';
$patternOutput = 'image_%s_preview';

$images = [
    'main_bg_pattern',
    'main_full_bg',
    'header_bg_pattern',
    'header_full_bg',
];
```

You can then use the masks with `sprintf()` like in `sprintf($patternInput, $imageName);`.

And after you've done all this, you revert to the original in your version control system and start over again with the knowledge gained on the way.

So first thing you should probably do now is to put your code under version control. That allows you do do these things easily without any fear of breaking something and doing little steps.

This could then result in the following:

```
$resizeWithDefaultFallback = function(&$subject) {
    $resize = [$this->model_tool_image, 'resize'];
    if (strlen($subject) && is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $subject)) {
        return $resize($this->data['upload_main_bg_pattern_image'], 100, 100);
    } else {
        return $resize('no_image.jpg', 100, 100);
    }
};

$images = [
    ['upload_main_bg_pattern_image',   'image_pattern_preview'       ],
    ['upload_main_full_bg_image',      'image_main_full_bg_preview'  ],
    ['upload_header_bg_pattern_image', 'image_header_pattern_preview'],
    ['upload_header_full_bg_image',    'image_header_full_bg_preview'],
];

foreach($images as $image) {
    $this->data[$image[1]] = $resizeWithDefaultFallback($this->data[$image[0]]);
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't really help much.

Comment: Well, it starts with the simple things.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to do `$data =& $this->data;`?  Without the `&`, you are copying the array, and therefore not updating the original `$this->data`.  http://ideone.com/tOYBUq

Comment: @RocketHazmat: PHP has copy on write, you normally do not need to care about that. Also I de-reference from `$this` to make the refactoring more easy. It's really a good trick to start with these very simple things (yes exactly that one you made a joke about ;)).

Comment: You make a good point.  I am defeated.  Please, just take my upvote :)

Comment: This work, but i get all images from 'upload_main_bg_pattern_image'

Answer (score 2):

Since all four code blocks appear to be doing the same thing, just with different keys for `data`, you could create a function that accepts the keys as strings and then run the function as many times as you need it.  You could also use a ternary operator to define the output file name, and then you just need to state the actual resizing code once.

```
function resizeImage(uploadKey, previewKey) {
    $fileName = (isset($this->data[uploadKey]) && $this->data[uploadKey] != "" && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $this->data[uploadKey])) ? $this->data[previewKey] : 'no_image.jpg';
    $this->data[previewKey] = $this->model_tool_image->resize(fileName, 100, 100);
}

resizeImage('upload_main_bg_pattern_image', 'image_pattern_preview');
resizeImage('upload_main_full_bg_image', 'image_main_full_bg_preview');
resizeImage('upload_header_bg_pattern_image', 'image_header_pattern_preview');
resizeImage('upload_header_full_bg_image', 'image_header_full_bg_preview');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function imageResize($data,$check)
{
    return (isset($this->data[$check]) && $this->data[$check] != "" && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $this->data[$check])) 
            ? $this->model_tool_image->resize($this->data[$check], 100, 100);
            : $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.jpg', 100, 100);
}

$this->data['image_pattern_preview'] = imageResize($data,"upload_main_bg_pattern_image");
$this->data['image_main_full_bg_preview'] = imageResize($data,"upload_main_full_bg_image");
$this->data['image_header_pattern_preview'] = imageResize($data,"upload_header_bg_pattern_image");
$this->data['image_header_full_bg_preview'] = imageResize($data,"upload_header_full_bg_image");
```

Comment: Thank you for all. I have something done so that all the functions will not work. 'll be back when will repair. sorry. Unable to verify the script, if the function will not work.